# Server Recommendation for windows server 2022

Tags: processor, pc, server, windows

*I'm new to maintaining users. As we currently don't have an active directory server on-prem, everything is in the cloud currently with Azure.*

I'm looking to buy a Dell Server for Windows 2022 Domain Controller for 20-30 Concurrent Users, with room to expand down the road. Based on others' experience with windows, what would be ideal for a Windows 2022 server deployment? I know they have minimum requirements, but I'm looking for specs that will not give me a headache down the road.

- Is having lots of memory ideal for this server?
- Is having lots of storage ideal for this server?
- Is one processor enough, or is two ideal? (under 16 cores)
- Is it better to have both cloud and local servers work together?

I appreciate any feedback you can provide.